# How to output 10 numbers in JavaScript using for loop one by one?

Tags: javascript

I am interested in outputting 10 numbers printed one by one using JavaScript.

The HTML code I used to output 10 numbers using JavaScript is:

```js
let z = "";
for (y = 0; y < 11; y = y + 1){
  x = y + 10;
  z = z + " Number " + x + " is printed. <br>";
}

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z
}, 1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>How to use For Loop in JavaScript</h2>
  <p>Output 10 numbers using for loop in Javascript.</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that the output is printed all at once after one second instead of printing the output one by one after one second.

How do we modify the code so that the individual output will be printed after one second?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your actual logic inside the interval

```js
let z = "";
let y = 0;

const interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (y >= 11) return clearInterval(interval);
  y++;
  const x = y + 10;
  z = z + " Number " + x + " is printed. <br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z
}, 1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>How to use For Loop in JavaScript</h2>
  <p>Output 10 numbers using for loop in Javascript.</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @WillD fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function with setTimeout instead of setInterval.

```js
function printDelay(max, iteration){
    const newLine = `Number ${iteration + 10} is printed.<br>`;

    const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    demo.innerHTML = demo.innerHTML + newLine;
    if(iteration < max){
      setTimeout(()=>printDelay(max, iteration + 1),1000);
    }
}

printDelay(10,1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>How to use For Loop in JavaScript</h2>
  <p>Output 10 numbers using for loop in Javascript.</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unique answer!....I've never thought of that one....

Answer (score 1):

```js
// init value
var i = 1; 
// func decleartion
function PrintOneByOne() { 
  // setTimeout
  // print for every 3 sec ~ 3000 ms
  // 
  setTimeout(function() {
    z = " Number " + i + " is printed. <br>";
    // append to element
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += z
    i++; 
    if (i <= 10) {
      PrintOneByOne(); 
    } 
  }, 3000)
}

// call func
PrintOneByOne();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>How to use For Loop in JavaScript</h2>
  <p>Output 10 numbers using for loop in Javascript.</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that this part of code is being runned all at once and before the setInterval

```
let z = "";
for (y = 0; y < 11; y = y + 1){
  x = y + 10;
  z = z + " Number " + x + " is printed. <br>";
}
```

If you want to print these lines one by one each one second, the best answer is to use setTimeout, like this:

```
function printNumberEachOneSecond(number) {
    if(number < 11){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += `Number ${number} is printed. <br>`;
        setTimeout(() => printNumberEachOneSecond(number + 1), 1000)
    }
}
printNumberEachOneSecond(1);
```

In this case we are using recursion to check if the number is below 11, if it is, we recall the same function after 1000 miliseconds(1 sec).

I don't encorage you to use setInterval because if you do it, you must clear this interval when you don't need it, and doing it may be quite tricky.

Edit:
If you reaaally need to use a for loop, use await/async, like this:

```
async function printNumberEachOneSecond() {
    for(let i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += `Number ${i} is printed. <br>`;
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
    }
}
printNumberEachOneSecond()
```

Comment: Good answer. This one's I've never thought of....

Answer (score 1):

you can also use promise and generator function...

As I told you in my first comment (to which you did not react), you must use a chain of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

this can result in JS code like this:

- there are a lot of technical things to know [(the MDN doc is there for that)](https://developer.mozilla.org)
  and I'm not some kind of teacher; anyway StackOverflow is not an online college.

start with [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/GeneratorFunction)

However, if you have any questions... ;)
-- but SO is already full of questions and answers on many technical points used here

```js
const 
  delay   = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
, xValues = function* (first,last) { for(i=first;i<=last;i++) yield i }
, pDemo   = document.querySelector('p#demo')
  ;
doMessages()

async function doMessages()
  {
  for await (x of xValues(10,20))
    {
    pDemo.appendChild( document.createTextNode(`Number ${x} is printed`))
    pDemo.appendChild( document.createElement(`br`))
    await delay(1000) 
    }
  }
```

```html
<h2>How to use For Loop in JavaScript</h2>
<p>Output 11 numbers using for loop in Javascript.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: promise and generator functions.....I never thought of that one.....

Comment: @Cambria  You asked to use a `for() loop`, and I give you two  :-)

Comment: Very nice...:-)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone answered according their mindset or teaching method.
I'm going to tell you a easiest way which can be achieved using two methods

01 - Set interval function,
02 - JS increment...

Now Focus Following

```js
      let totalnum = 10; // loop limit
      let minnum = 0; // starting point
      let printspeed = 0.5 //Print Speed in seconds
      let printer = setInterval(function () { // interval function
        minnum ++; // increment
        if (minnum > totalnum) {
          clearInterval(printer);
        } else {
          // Printing code
          let div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = minnum + ' - printed';
          document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(div);
        }
      }, printspeed * 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Good answer!...another approach....